# Oracle - Optimize update

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to update value in the table. Given script for update lasts indefinitely. 
Would you consult me, how to optimize this update?
Here is script:

```
UPDATE rp_dtls e
  SET e.C_RNG =(SELECT b.cod
                FROM (SELECT rn0.code          cod,
                      a.n_datavalue n_datavalue,
                      a.c_ins           c_ins,
                      a.related_Account related_Account,
                      a.d_periodlastday d_periodlastday,
                      a.N_PACKETINFOID  N_PACKETINFOID
                 FROM (SELECT SUM(t.n_datavalue) n_datavalue,
                              t.c_ins,
                              t.related_Account,
                              t.d_periodlastday,
                              t.N_PACKETINFOID
                         FROM rp_dtls t
                        WHERE t.d_periodlastday = to_date('31.10.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                          AND t.n_packetinfoid = (SELECT MAX(N_PACKETINFOID)
                                 FROM rp_dtls 
                                WHERE d_periodlastday =
                                      to_date('31.10.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
                          AND t.c_ins IN ('F04000', 'F02205')
                        GROUP BY t.c_ins,
                                 t.related_Account,
                                 t.d_periodlastday,
                                 t.N_PACKETINFOID,
                                 t.c_ins) a
                 LEFT JOIN rp_rng rn0
                   ON a.n_datavalue BETWEEN rn0.val_min AND rn0.val_max) b
        WHERE b.c_ins = e.c_ins
          AND b.related_Account = e.related_Account
          AND b.d_periodlastday = e.d_periodlastday
          AND b.N_PACKETINFOID = e.N_PACKETINFOID)**
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing you can do is remove the non required columns from the sub queries select statement

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I can remove only one column, other columns I need for join :(

Comment: what is the primary key of rp_dtls ???

Comment: This is temporary table, created another user. Not created by me. There is not primary key.

Comment: Maybe more of a question to the experts here, but I sometimes think that execution may be faster if you make a function out of the whole subquery. If only returning 1 value (1 column) that would technically work, no doubt. But faster ? It's easy to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several queries - break it down into sections e.g. how long does it take to execute

```
SELECT SUM(t.n_datavalue) n_datavalue,
                          t.c_ins,
                          t.related_Account,
                          t.d_periodlastday,
                          t.N_PACKETINFOID
                     FROM rp_dtls t
                    WHERE t.d_periodlastday = to_date('31.10.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                      AND t.n_packetinfoid = (SELECT MAX(N_PACKETINFOID)
                             FROM rp_dtls 
                            WHERE d_periodlastday =
                                  to_date('31.10.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
                      AND t.c_ins IN ('F04000', 'F02205')
                    GROUP BY t.c_ins,
                             t.related_Account,
                             t.d_periodlastday,
                             t.N_PACKETINFOID,
                             t.c_ins
```

?

You should look at the query plan for each each statement e.g. explain plan for select...
This may suggest adding an index on d_periodlastday, c_ins or N_PACKETINFOID for example. Indexes on the columns you are trying to update may slow the update because they require part of the index to rebuild.

So break into stages and time and analyse the parts of the query.

PS It won't last for ever - although it may seem like a long time! If you have some free time and no one else is using the box let it run and see what happens (you may run out of memory).